# How Modify Alert preview on Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a javascript (of which I am not an expert) that returns a query I do through a Python service to a Mongodb database.

That query comes in the ready format in the following way

> [{CHAIN: "STREET ELM, ELMER", CODE: "1234"}, {CHAIN: "STREET LM, LMAO", CODE: "5678"}]

The solution I saw was to create a table that returned that result to show it to the user. I have to make a couple of modifications:

One is to return the complete cursor of the database, until now only returns the string I have written in the HTML, but in the Database I make a kind of LIKE that returns all the strings that contain that string. That is, when I write LM, the database returns the previous list, but in the HTML I only get

> {CHAIN: "STREET LM, LMAO", CODE: "5678"}

The second thing I have to do is modify the window that appears when I click on an element of that table. Before clicking on the table, I get the result

> STREET STREET LM, LMAO

but now now I have to concatenate, apart from the result of the string, the code and show something like

> STREET STREET LM, LMAO 5678

Will they have an idea of ​​how I can modify that? I have no idea and I've had quite a while without finding the how

Thats is my code:

```
<style>
            table tr:not(:first-child){
                cursor: pointer;transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            }
            table tr:not(:first-child):hover{background-color: #ddd;}
            table td {border: 1px #DDD solid; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;}
</style>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cantidad">
        Cantidad de elementos sugeridos:
        <input type="radio" id="10" name="cant" value="10" checked="checked"> 10
        <input type="radio" id="15" name="cant" value="15"> 15
        <input type="radio" id="20" name="cant" value="20"> 20
        </div>
        <div id="country">
        Seleccione País:
        <select name="pais">
        <option value="ARGENTINA" selected="selected">ARGENTINA</option> 
        <option value="PARAGUAY">PARAGUAY</option> 
        <option value="URUGUAY">URUGUAY</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        Ingrese la calle a buscar, la localidad, partido/depto.y provincia en cualquier orden.<br>
        Para obtener mejor resultado en la búsqueda, ponga entre comillas los nombres compuestos<br>
        Por ejemplo: "san martin", etc.<br>
        <input id="CHAIN" type="text" placeholder="ingrese el string para buscar una calle" autocomplete="off" size="80"/>
        <table id="table">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var parsedJSON;
    var ex = document.getElementsByName('pais')[0];
    function actualiza () {
        var selected_pais= ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].text;
            var params = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5007/suggestStreetName',
                //data: JSON.stringify({ "CHAIN": $("#chain").val() }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                    $("#table tr").remove();
                    var tableRef = document.getElementById('table');
                    for (var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) {
                        var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(0);
                        var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
                        /*newCell.onclick = function () {  tableText(this);  };*/
                        newCell.onclick = function () {  tableText(this);  };
                        var newText  = document.createTextNode(parsedJSON[i].CHAIN);
                        var newText2  = document.createTextNode(parsedJSON[i].CODIGO);
                        newCell.appendChild(newText);
                    }
                    console.log(selected_pais);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            };
        if ($("#chain").val().length > 0) {
            cantidad = "10";
            if (document.getElementById('10').checked) {
                cantidad = "10";
            } else {
                if (document.getElementById('15').checked) {
                    cantidad = "15";
                } else {
                    cantidad = "20";
                }
             };
             if (selected_pais == 'ARGENTINA') {
                console.log("Pais en el IF: ",selected_pais);
                params.data = JSON.stringify({ "CHAIN": $("#chain").val(), "CANTIDAD": cantidad }),
                params.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5007/suggestStreetName';
                }
            else if (selected_pais == 'PARAGUAY') {
                console.log("Pais en el IF: ",selected_pais);
                params.data = JSON.stringify({ "CHAIN": $("#chain").val(), "CANTIDAD": cantidad }),
                params.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5008/suggestStreetName';
                }
            else if (selected_pais == 'URUGUAY') {
                console.log("Pais en el IF: ",selected_pais);
                params.data = JSON.stringify({ "CHAIN": $("#chain").val(), "CANTIDAD": cantidad }),
                params.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5009/suggestStreetName'
                }
            else {
                params.data = JSON.stringify({ "CHAIN": $("#chain").val(), "CANTIDAD": cantidad }),
                params.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5007/suggestStreetName'
                }
            $.ajax(params);
        } else {
                 document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    $("#chain").keyup(function (e) {
        actualiza();
    });

    $('input[type=radio][name=cant]').change(function() {
        console.log('Imprime radio button');
        actualiza();
    });

    $('select[name=pais]').change(function() {
        console.log('Imprime pais');
        $("#table tr").remove();
        $("#chain").val(undefined);
        console.log('Limpia Cadena');
        actualiza();
    });

function tableText(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
}


function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}


</script>
```

Comment: You really should avoid using a translator from Spanish to English to post your questions, or at least check the translated text before posting it since it could be hard for people that don't know Spanish to understand properly your issue. 

Also, I see something that made me curious. In your success function in AJAX you are calling `parsedJSON[i].STRING` which (as you specified in your question) the structure of the JSON string returned has 'CHAIN` and `CODE` index. So, what happens if you use:

`parsedJSON[i].CHAIN` and `parsedJSON[i].CODE`

Comment: forgive me, Kelly, I made the change

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the data you got via ajax in a global variable, then create a function to retrieve the data you want by assigning to the onclick event a function, ex: function FindValues(position)... something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) {
    var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(0);
    var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.onclick = FindValues(i);
    var newText  = document.createTextNode(parsedJSON[i].CHAIN);
    var newText2  = document.createTextNode(parsedJSON[i].CODIGO);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

in FindValues(position) you would have the data you need and should be able to do whatever you may need.

Hope this helps

Cheers